# Can I fire a GTM tag on both page view and history change without needing separate triggers?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My site uses `pushState` and `popState` do I need to have 2 separate triggers for page views (i.e. when the page first loads) and history changes (i.e. javascript backed navigation)?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but a GTM tag can be fired based on multiple triggers. So you could fire on All Pages (ie. pageview), and also on history change.

Comment: @nyuen I mean can i use a single trigger so I don't have to constantly make 2.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with a Custom HTML tag which would listen for either the pageview event `gtm.js` or the history change event `gtm.historyChange`. As soon as either one occurs, then you can push a custom event `myEvent` which can be used to fire your tag.